# Searching two internal html files simultaneously with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP code (index.php) for searching keywords in two html files (data.html & data2.html). When I search a keyword, such as "Ann", would it be possible to parse both html files and shows the line matching the keyword (i.e. This is Ann.)? The source codes are as follows:

**index.php**

```html
<?php
$search = $_GET['keyword'];
$data = file('data.html');

$check = false;
foreach($data as $match)
{
  if(strpos($match, $search) !== false)
  {
    $check = true;
    $output = '<div>'.$match.'<div>';
    echo $output;

  }
}
?>
```

**data.html**

```html
This is Ann.
This is Bob.
This is Candy.
```

**data2.html**

```html
This is Ann.
This is Peter.
This is Bob.
```

Many thanks for help.

Comment: And what's your question exactly? You can't open second file and search it too or what?

Comment: I would like to know how to modify the code in index.html so that it can parse two files at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like that;

```
<?php

$search = $_GET['keyword'];
$data = file('data.txt');
$data2 = file('data2.txt');

$datas = Array($data, $data2);
foreach($datas as $index => $data){
    foreach($data as $lineNumber => $match )
    {
      if(strpos($match, $search) !== false)
      {
        echo "<div><b>$index 'th file</b>. Line number: $lineNumber . Match: $match <br />";
      }
    }
}
?>
```

If you need read more than one file at the same time you just add like data3 and add also array too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, merdincz!